# Left alignement and right alignement

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

I would like to realize an alignment as follows, with `array` environment by preference:

```
abcde fghijk
lmnnnnn  opq
rstuvwxyz
```

So, `abcde` and `lmnnnnn` are left aligned; `fghijk` and `opq` are right aligned. There are some space between `abcde` and `fghijk`.

`rstuvwxyz` is left aligned with the 2 first rows; putting it in the center of its row is OK as well...

Coud anyone help?

Comment: Then you should read something about how to use the [`array`](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.html#array) environment.

Comment: Haven't found the solution...

Comment: Is there supposed to be overlap between `fghijk` on one line and `lmnnnnn` on the next?

Comment: yes, it is...@Mico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely I'm misunderstanding your question...

Take a look at this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\emph{Something like this (in math mode)?}

\vspace{10pt}

\(
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}r@{}}
\text{abcde}&\text{fghijk}\\
\text{lmnnnnn}&\text{opq}\\
\text{rstuvwxyz}
\end{array}
\)

\vspace{20pt}

\emph{or like this?}

\vspace{10pt}

\(
\begin{array}{@{}p{0.85cm}r@{}}
\text{abcde}&\text{fghijk}\\
\text{lmnnnnn}&\text{opq}\\
\text{rstuvwxyz}
\end{array}
\)

\vspace{20pt}

\emph{Or something like this (in text mode)?}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}r@{}}
abcde&fghijk\\
lmnnnnn&opq\\
rstuvwxyz
\end{tabular}

\vspace{20pt}

\emph{or like this?}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.85cm}r@{}}
abcde&fghijk\\
lmnnnnn&opq\\
rstuvwxyz
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]